# SWIFT signal SIGABRT error thread1

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to code a simple app where you input 2 numbers in textfields and return the sum of them in iOS app. The problem is that I am getting Thread 1 signal SIGABRT error and I can't seem to find any fix for this.

This is the code:

```
@IBOutlet var result: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var firstnum: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var secondnum: UITextField!

@IBAction func add (sender: UIButton) {

    var a = firstnum.text.toInt();
    var b = secondnum.text.toInt();

    var c = a!+b!;


    result.text = "\(c)";

}
```

Comment: Show your error log.

Comment: the error line is 
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate { in appdelegate.swift

Answer (score 0):

You should check your connections; if you have a label, textfield, etc connected from the main storyboard to the view controller, check to see if your label in Main.storyboard is linked to it by opening the right side panel and selecting the last bar. It will show you all the outlets that label has.

This occurs when you make a connection from the Main.storyboard to the ViewController.swift, and you remove the text in the ViewController.swift, but you do not remove the connection.

For more information, watch this video:
[iOS Programming: How to fix thread 1 signal sigabrt in xcode 6](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkcqBIS8Swc)

I hope this helps.